# Create a new DbContext or use the injected DbContext when calling a stored procedure in Entity Core?

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework-core, dbcontext

What is the proper way to execute a stored procedure (using the ADO method) in Entity Core?

Should I use the injected dbcontext or should I create a new one?

```
public class ContactController
{
    private readonly MyDbContext _context;


    public ContactController(MyDbContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }


    public IActionResult Search(ContactSearchModel csm, int page)
    {
        //execute using the injected _context?
        using (var command = _context.Database.GetDbConnection().CreateCommand())
        {
            //...
        }

        //or create a new context?
        using (var newContext = new MyDbContext())
        {
            using (var command = newContext.Database.GetDbConnection().CreateCommand())
            {
                //...
            }
         }

    }
}
```

Comment: Use the injected one, not create a new one. Benefit: You can use the same transaction on SaveChanges along with the other modifications you may do with the context keeping the Unit of Work for the request.

Answer (score 2):

There shouldn't be any reason to not use the injected one.

If you are asking just because you are only reading the data and want it to be quick, and you're worried about tracking or something, you should just call `.AsNoTracking()` when calling the DB for your stored proc.

An example:

```
var users = _context.Users
    .FromSql("EXECUTE dbo.MyUserStoredProc")
    .AsNoTracking()
    .ToList();
```

See these EF Core docs on [Raw SQL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/raw-sql#basic-raw-sql-queries) and [No Tracking](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/tracking#no-tracking-queries).